# Best way to have a group of "color switching" buttons in Rails

Tags: javascript

What's the best way to have a group of buttons and switch the color between them?

If click in second button, only the second button changes to red:

[image]

And if click in fourth button, only the fourth button will be red, the other will be blue:

[image]

Comment: just change the css or class of the button using jQuery when click of the button like this $('.btn').click(function(){$(this).addClass('red-background')});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function(){
    var $btns = $(".btns");
    $btns.click(function(e){
      $btns.removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

put a class to all buttons, eg: buttons

(function(){

```
$(".buttons").click(function(e){
  $(this).css("background-color","red");
})
```

})